# Why my interstitial test ad is not showing up?

Tags: admob, ads, interstitial

I scripted just as admob website asked and nothing is showing up on

I tried in different activities, for 48 hours, no results yet

I'm receiving an error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.isotronic.adesivoschaves, PID: 1065
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.isotronic.adesivoschaves/com.example.samplestickerapp.StickerPackDetailsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3488)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.samplestickerapp.StickerPackDetailsActivity.onCreate(StickerPackDetailsActivity.java:131)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7955)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7944)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3463)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3635) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7860) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 

  mInterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(new FullScreenContentCallback(){
            @Override
            public void onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when fullscreen content is dismissed.
                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was dismissed.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(AdError adError) {
                // Called when fullscreen content failed to show.
                Log.d("TAG", "The ad failed to show.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                // Called when fullscreen content is shown.
                // Make sure to set your reference to null so you don't
                // show it a second time.
                mInterstitialAd = null;
                Log.d("TAG", "The ad was shown.");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please have a look to the log message. It tells you why ad is not shown. Make sure to use test ads. Log also tells you the line how to add test device.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.ads.interstitial.InterstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback(com.google.android.gms.ads.FullScreenContentCallback)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.samplestickerapp.StickerPackDetailsActivity.onCreate(StickerPackDetailsActivity.java:125)

Comment: yes, looks like that's it. Check if mInterstitialAd is equal NULL ... or better check your implementation about mInterstitialAd.

Answer (score 13):

Please, make sure `interstitialAd.setFullScreenContentCallback` is inside `onAdLoaded` function.

Check this AdMob [example](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/admob/InterstitialExample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/example/interstitialexample/MyActivity.java)